# Converting psd to android xml

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been checking out on photoshop lately in developing mobile ui and found out it to be really great, the problem is in the conversion to xml layout.

After an internet search i saw there are companies doing this and I was intrigued and wanted to know how they do it since in photoshop there is no option to convert psd to xml layout

Is it possible to convert psd files to xml by export or do i have to code the xml layouts using psd as a visual tool having a view of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people may well do this by hand, using the Photoshop file as a guide and building the XML / Android layout file from scratch, but I would say that it's much more likely that any company doing this professionally would be using some kind of plugin and / or scripting to perform the task.

There is a plugin called Export Kit (and I'm sure there are others) which includes this kind of functionality. They offer a free trial so maybe that would be a good starting point for you.